# Create tidy dataset from an untidy one with two variables per column and implicit missings

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I have an untidy dataset that combines two variables (some missing) in each of two columns (a small subsample in the data frame 'test' below). I'm struggling to create the desired tidy dataset below.

```
untidy <- structure(list(`N [ears]` = c("173", "60", "54 [96]", "168 [328]", 
"906 [1685]"), `% Otorrhea` = c("58.61%", "13.30%", "11.11%", 
"52.38%", "14.79% [10.45%]")), .Names = c("N [ears]", "% Otorrhea"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Desired data frame

```
N_patients  N_ears  pct_patients  pct_ears
173         NA      58.61           NA
 60         NA      13.30           NA
 54         96      11.11           NA
168        328      14.79        10.45
```

Thanks!

Seems there is always an edge case - where both answers fail to consider something about the 5th row. Seems to be just a regex issue.  Suggestions on how to fix?

```
untidy_2 <- structure(list(`N [ears]` = c("173", "60", "54 [96]", "168 [328]", 
                                          "906 [1685]"), `% Otorrhea` = c("58.61%", "13.30%", "11.11%", 
                                                                          "52.38%", "14.79% [10.45%]")), .Names = c("N [ears]", "% Otorrhea"
                                                                          ), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                          ))
```

ie. row 5, [35.55%] is parsed as pct_patients

```
   N [ears] % Otorrhea N_patients N_ears pct_patients pct_ears
1       173     58.61%        173     NA        58.61       NA
2        60     13.30%         60     NA        13.30       NA
3   54 [96]     11.11%         54     96        11.11       NA
4 168 [328]     52.38%        168    328        52.38       NA
5  75 [150]   [35.33%]         75    150        35.33       NA
```

Comment: I thought to use stringr{str_extract_all} to extract numbers of two types, in [ ] and not enclosed, or alternatively tidyr{separate} to split the columns. In either case, would seem to need to use a regular expression.  Have failed in this aspect thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer for my actual dataset was provided by in the comment by
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire

Shown below, wrapped in a simple funtion.

```
  library(tidyverse)

    make_tidy <- function(untidy){
       tidy <- untidy %>% 
       separate_(colnames(untidy)[1], c('N_patients', 'N_ears'), fill = 'right', extra = 'drop', convert = TRUE) %>% 
       separate_(colnames(untidy)[2], c('pct_patients', 'pct_ears'), sep = '[^\\d.]+', extra = 'drop', convert = TRUE)
    }

    tidy_2 <- make_tidy(untidy_2)
```

Correctly parses untidy_2

```
> tidy_2
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  N_patients N_ears pct_patients pct_ears
*      <int>  <int>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1        173     NA        58.61       NA
2         60     NA        13.30       NA
3         54     96        11.11       NA
4        168    328        52.38       NA
5        906   1685        14.79    10.45
```

Answer (score 2):

Happily, this is pretty easy with the `tidyr` package in the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- structure(list(`N [ears]` = c("173", "60", "54 [96]", "168 [328]", "906 [1685]"), 
                       `% Otorrhea` = c("58.61%", "13.30%", "11.11%", "52.38%", "14.79% [10.45%]")), 
                  Names = c("N [ears]", "% Otorrhea"), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

test %>% 
    separate(`N [ears]`, into = c("N_patients", "N_ears"), sep = "\\s\\[", fill = "right") %>%
    separate(`% Otorrhea`, into = c("pct_patients", "pct_ears"), sep = "\\s\\[", fill = "right") %>%
    mutate_each(funs(parse_number))
#>   N_patients N_ears pct_patients pct_ears
#> 1        173     NA        58.61       NA
#> 2         60     NA        13.30       NA
#> 3         54     96        11.11       NA
#> 4        168    328        52.38       NA
#> 5        906   1685        14.79    10.45
```

Comment: If you use `sep = '[^\\d.]+'` and  `convert = TRUE` in `separate`, you can skip the `parse_number`, e.g. `test %>% 
    separate(\`N [ears]\`, c('N_patients', 'N_ears'), fill = 'right', extra = 'drop', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    separate(\`% Otorrhea\`, c('pct_patients', 'pct_ears'), sep = '[^\\d.]+', extra = 'drop', convert = TRUE)`. Also check out `type_convert`.

Comment: Just found an edge case that I can't figure out.  I've edited my original post to reflect this new row of data (row 5).  Thanks!

Comment: The 1st two answers fail on my edge case (e.g test_2, row 5).  The code in the comment above fixes this issue in all cases I've examined.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative with `extract()` function with regular expressions:

```
library(tidyr)
test %>% 
        extract(`N [ears]`, into = c("N_patients", "N_ears"), 
                            regex = "^(\\d+)(?:\\s\\[(\\d+)\\])?$") %>% 
        extract(`% Otorrhea`, into = c("pct_patients", "pct_ears"), 
                              regex = "^([.0-9]+)%(?:\\s\\[([.0-9]+)%\\])?$")

#  N_patients N_ears pct_patients pct_ears
#1        173   <NA>        58.61     <NA>
#2         60   <NA>        13.30     <NA>
#3         54     96        11.11     <NA>
#4        168    328        52.38     <NA>
#5        906   1685        14.79    10.45
```

Here we can use non-capture group `(?:...)` with `?` to capture optional ears columns.